# Is Polymorphism (significantly)slower than direct implementations?

Tags: java

So I have this class which is basically an implemented ArrayList, I was hoping to make the code which uses this class run faster by making it use the java implementations, instead, it ran almost twice as slow. Is there any obvious reason behind this that I'm missing? **Is it meant to be slower this way?**

**The original handwritten code:**

```
public class VertexSet {
    private int[] _set = null;
    private int _sp;
    public final static int INIT_SIZE = 10, INC = 30;

    public VertexSet() {
        _set = new int[INIT_SIZE];
        _sp = 0;
    }

    public VertexSet(VertexSet ot) {
        _set = new int[INIT_SIZE];
        _sp = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < ot.size(); ++i) this.add(ot.at(i));
    }

    public void add(int a) {
        if(_sp == _set.length) resize();
        _set[_sp] = a;
        ++_sp;
    }
    public int size() {return _sp;}
    public int at(int i) {return _set[i];}

    public String toString() {
        String ans = "Set: |" + size() + "| ";
        for(int i = 0; i < size(); ++i) ans+=this.at(i) + ", ";
        return ans;
    }

    public String toFile() {
        String ans = " ";
        for(int i = 0; i < size(); ++i) ans += this.at(i) + ", ";
        return ans;
    }
    /**
     * this method computes the intersection between this set and ot set.
     * @param ot - the other set
     */
    public VertexSet intersection(VertexSet ot) {
        VertexSet ans = new VertexSet();
        int i1 = 0, i2 = 0, a1, a2;
        while(i1<this.size() & i2 < ot.size()) {
            a1=this.at(i1);
            a2 = ot.at(i2);
            if(a1 == a2) {
                ans.add(a1); ++i1; ++i2;}
            else if(a1 < a2) {++i1;}
            else ++i2;
        }
        return ans;
    }

    private void resize() {
        int[] tmp = new int[_sp + INC];
        for(int i = 0; i < _sp; ++i) tmp[i] = _set[i];
        _set = tmp;
    }

}
```

**The handwritten code after extending the java implementations:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class VertexSet extends ArrayList<Integer>{
    public final static int INIT_SIZE = 10;

    public VertexSet() {
        super(INIT_SIZE);
    }

    public VertexSet(VertexSet ot) {
        super(ot);
    }

    public int at(int i) {return get(i);}

    public String toString() {
        String ans = "Set: |" + size() + "| ";
        for(int i = 0; i < size(); ++i) ans+=this.at(i) + ", ";
        return ans;
    }

    public String toFile() {
        String ans = " ";
        for(int i = 0; i < size(); ++i) ans += this.at(i) + ", ";
        return ans;
    }
    /**
     * this method computes the intersection between this set and ot set.
     * @param ot - the other set
     */
    public VertexSet intersection(VertexSet ot) {
        VertexSet ans = new VertexSet();
        int i1 = 0, i2 = 0, a1, a2;
        while(i1<this.size() & i2 < ot.size()) {
            a1=this.at(i1);
            a2 = ot.at(i2);
            if(a1 == a2) {
                ans.add(a1); ++i1; ++i2;}
            else if(a1 < a2) {++i1;}
            else ++i2;
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Comment: Twice as slow for what operations? (In both implementations your `toString` and `toFile` operations are painful in terms of repeated string concatenation, for one thing...) Have you taken into account that when you use `ArrayList`, you'll be boxing every value? You're not really just comparing polymorphism here...

Comment: "boxing every value" you mean with ints being used as objects? Does that make a difference here? And does it matter what operations was it slow with? Both are meant to have the same complexity and both were tested with the same input.

Comment: Yes, it makes a difference - it means you're doing more work. And yes, it matters what operations it was slow with, because that affects where the differences are. As another example of a difference, your use of an `int[]` in the hand-written class means to get the value of an element as an `int` you *just* need the array - whereas when it's an `Object[]`, you obtain the reference from the array, then the `int` value from the object it refers to. It would be a much more reasonable comparison if you were using a class type.

Comment: Boxing also means you should check `a1.equals(a2)` rather than `a1 == a2` in the `intersection` method.

Comment: You should also check out Guava libraries as they have collection types dealing only with primitives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is a great example why to **not** do it that way. You are concerned about performance; but you have no real understanding on what is going on behind the backgrounds. So, instead of coming up with your own implementations ... you should first understand ... if there is a problem at all. And I think there are really very few real world scenarios were the minor cost of inheritance for collections requires you to use custom list classes (see http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization ).

The only exception might be when you are dealing with primitive types; as the Collection stuff only works for reference (aka Object types). Then the bill becomes really expensive; as an ArrayList with 10 million Integer objects "costs" much more than an array with 10 million ints.

You came up with a "correct" implementation; but as others have pointed out --- some methods do unnecessary things that might explain these performance issues.

Please keep in mind: the whole collections framework was designed, and implemented by **expert** java programmers. Why do you think that your skills will match the skills of these people?!

This is not meant as an insult - I am just pointing out that creating such libraries is an task that is better left to subject-matter experts.

For example, in the "Scala" world the language creators really differentiate between "normal users" (that write "normal applications") and those people that want to design/implement frameworks/libraries. And it is commonly accepted that the later task requires a **much** deeper insight into the concepts and features of the Scala programming language. It is not much different in Java.

Besides: do you know when the java just-in-time compiler works best? It works best when the incoming java bytecode looks like the code that "most people" write. There have been many examples when people tried to optimize their Java source code ... to later realize that their very special code lead to insufficient performance; as the JIT was not able to optimize that "unusual" bytecode.

Comment: Heh, the part where I know expert programmers made those implementations is exactly why I wanted to use their implementations instead, so no offense taken :P And the reason I'm stuck with this class instead of just using something from java is that the rest of the code is huge and already relies on this class already, not that it would matter though, since, like you've mentioned, using ints instead of Integers if/when I can is better. Anyway, this pretty much covers everything so thank you for the great answer :)